# split text file into parts according to the lines beginning with integer

Tags: awk, split, text-files

I'm using a mac and I have checked to find that I'm able to use split or awk. The problem that I face at the moment is that I have a large text file which has chapters from a korean novel. I want it to be split into parts based on the integers (chapter numbers).

```
00001====================
서(序)



나는,

재능이 없었다. 

못생겼다. 

친구도 없다. 

집안도 최악이었다. 

그러므로 모두가 나를 경멸했다.

모든 걸 부정당하며 끝까지 살아갔다.

그래서

재능없는 놈은 죽으란 말이냐? 

그럼 죽겠다. 

너희가 원하는 대로 죽어 주겠다.

죽고 나서 또 다시 도전해 주겠다. 

이 개같은 세상을 죽여버릴 때까지!


00002====================
첫 번째 죽음



나는 오늘도 암울한 삶을 이어가고 있었다.
```

This is a simple example from the text file. Is it possible to either use split or awk command to split the text file into many parts according to chapter numbers? If so please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/{ close(fn); fn = "file_part"int($0); next }fn{ print > fn }' file
```

As a result you'll get files like `file_part1`, `file_part2`, `...`

Comment: Thanks for input. I get this reply when i tried your method `awk '/^[0-9]+/{ fn = "file_part"int($0); next }{ print > fn }' RS.txt
awk: null file name in print or getline
 input record number 1, file RS.txt
 source line number 1`

Comment: perhaps  `/^[0-9]+=+/` to minimize false positives\

Comment: @karafka, same error `awk: null file name in print or getline
 input record number 1, file RS.txt
 source line number 1`

Comment: @Ali, you probably have an input file with empty first lines, use my update

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, it works but stops at part 17.. `awk: chapter17 makes too many open files
 input record number 3789, file RS.txt
 source line number 1`

Comment: add `close(fn);` before `fn = "..`

Comment: thanks karafka.. it seems the previous ones had to be closed before opening new ones :)

Comment: One more small question. Is it possible to make the output files as .txt files?

Comment: @Ali, just change to `fn = "file_part" int($0) ".txt"`